# How to import a resource in Eclipse plugin stylesheet?

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

To create an Eclipse plugin, I need to import/use some resources into a stylesheet.
All the necessary files reside into the plugin package and are correctly build with no errors into the final .jar.

I have this folder/files in plugin package:

```
> my.plugin.package.name
    > META-INF/
        > MANIFEST.MF
    > resources/
        > css/
            > base-stylesheet.css
            > win-stylesheet.css
            > linux-stylesheet.css
            > ...
        > images/
            > mytexture.png
            > ...
    > plugin.xml
    > ...
```

in *win-stylesheet.css* I want to import *base-stylesheet.css* and use *mytexture.png*, so into the CSS I do:

```
@import url("base-stylesheet.css");
#elemId {
    background-image: url(../images/mytexture.png);
}
```

unfortunately, these gives a **MalformedURLException**, I noticed also that:

- using character **"** or **'** or nothing to delimit the url string give the same error;
- using `@import url("/base-stylesheet.css")` or `@import url("./base-stylesheet.css")` works perfecly when running/debugging the plugin into a second Eclipse instance but silently fails with the same error when the plugin jar is installed in Eclipse;
- using `@import url("platform:/plugin/my.plugin.id/resources/css/base-stylesheet.css")` or `@import url("platform://plugin/my.plugin.id/resources/css/base-stylesheet.css")` where `my.plugin.id` is the *Bundle-SymbolicName* assigned in *MANIFEST.MF* give the same error both when running/debugging the plugin and when using it after installing the jar.

I suspect that the workspace directory is automatically assigned to `platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this for Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) product CSS styling or is it some other use of CSS?

Comment: yes it's for Eclipse 4.2+ styling

Comment: Problem is still unsolved, is it possible that Eclipse has a such basic bug or something is missing?

Comment: I have been trying to find any bug reports for this but without success.

Comment: thanks @greg-449, I searched a lot for some documentation about it but I've found nothing useful to solve it. If none will know how to solve, I'll try to add a bug report to Eclipse..

Answer (score 2):

The existing Eclipse stylesheets just use

```
@import url("base-stylesheet.css");
```

for css in the same directory.

For resources you specify the location in the `applicationCSSResources` property in the product extension point properties:

```xml
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="%product.name"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
      <property
           name="applicationCSSResources"
           value="platform:/plugin/my.plugin.package.name/images/">
      </property>
```

Comment: `@import url("base-stylesheet.css")` gives the error when the 'import' is executed, as written in the question, I tried also without the semicolon.

Comment: Sorry should have semicolon, edited answer. It doesn't have any leading / or ./

Comment: Importing in this way gives the MalformedURLException, I don't know if it's supposed to be the right behavior or it's a platform bug, have you same basic running example?

Comment: I'm testing using a pure e4 application. Do you have a `applicationCSS` or `cssTheme` property in the product properties?

Comment: My manifest is very similar to [this](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/blob/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.plugin/plugin.xml) , there is no <product> property, stylesheets are declared into the <theme> properties.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post "[Import CSS files in Eclipse Luna M6](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/11/import-css-files-in-eclipse-luna-m6/)" from Lars Vogel seems to imply that the import now works, meaning you need at least an Eclipse 4.4 Luna M6.

Not only that 4.4 M6 release comes with a [dark theme for the IDE](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M6-201403061200/news/), it also lists:

> **CSS includes**
>
> CSS files for Eclipse can now include other CSS files via the `@import url("platform:/plugin/Bundle-Symbolic-Name/path/file.extension");` statement.
> This allows easy reuse of existing style sheets.

For instance (Vogel's post):

> In your RCP application, create a `/css/default.css` file with only one instruction:

```
@import url(“platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.themes/css/e4-dark.css”);
```

> Add `org.eclipse.ui.themes` to your RCP product and add the `applicationCSS` property pointing to `platform:/plugin/test/css/default.css` in your `product` extension point.

Comment: This sorted out my particular problem, which turned out to that CSS styling was working fine from the IDE but not from the (Tycho) built product. CSS file load was failing as @import was using file:// protocol and silently throwing an exception as doesn't work when accessing inside a jar. platform  URI saved the day!